# rhino mocks ref param constraint

Tags: constraints, rhino-mocks, ref

I am very new to RhinoMocks (first time).

This is my method declaration:

```
void SetXmlValue(ref string path, ref string Value);
```

I need to verify that for the given input, when SetXmlValue is called, it gets called with particular values for path and value

I have tried a few options including:

```
_mockClass.Expect(o => o.SetXmlValue(ref Arg<string>.Ref(Rhino.Mocks.Constraints.Is.Equal(path), "somepath").Dummy ,ref Arg<string>.Ref(Rhino.Mocks.Constraints.Is.Equal(value), "somevalue").Dummy));

_mockClass.Expect(o => o.SetXmlValue(ref Arg<string>.Out(path).Dummy, ref Arg<string>.Out(value).Dummy))
```

However, I am not able to confirm that the SetXmlValue method was called with the parameters I am expecting it to call.

Any inputs?

Answer (score 0):

This verifies that the method gets called with the correct params:

```
_mockClass.Stub(x => x.SetXmlValue(null, null))
                   .IgnoreArguments()
                   .WhenCalled(invocation => Assert.AreEqual("somepath", invocation.Arguments[0]));
                   .WhenCalled(invocation => Assert.AreEqual("somevalue", invocation.Arguments[1]));        

_mockClass.VerifyAllExpectations();
```

**EDIT**
Just found another way of doing this:

```
 _mockClass.GetArgumentsForCallsMadeOn(x => x.SetXmlValue(null, null));
 Assert.AreEqual("somepath", arguments[0][0]);
 Assert.AreEqual("somevalue", arguments[0][1]);
```

The second example was useful, when I used Gherkin scenarios and the step definition of result had to be the last one (which is why I could not set the expectations beforehand).

In this case arguments[0] contains the parameters when SetXmlValue() was called first time, arguments[1] contains the parameters when SetXmlValue() was called second time, and so on.